# Error installing vim after upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies, vim

Today I upgraded my ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. The upgrade was successful.

But when I tried to install vim, it throws error.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve it? I tried to install libpython3.6, but it throws the unmet dependencies error.

Comment: what is the unmet dependencies for libpython3.6

Comment: @Adem libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4) but 3.6.13-1+xenial2 is to be installed

Comment: try installing that

Comment: It is already installed the latest version, but still the problem persists

Comment: are there any more dependecies

Comment: Nope, there are not more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126862/discussion-between-adem-and-monojit-sarkar).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the unmet dependencies until one of the dependencies are unavailble. Install the DEB file for that dependency, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix broken dependencies by installing [default python versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/python3.6) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.6=3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4 libpython3.6-minimal=3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4 libpython3.6-stdlib=3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4 python3.6=3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4 python3.6-minimal=3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4
```

and then install Vim.